# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ':' Python

Tags: python, file, file-management

I'am trying to add some new features to my file-management system. But I get struck with the following. I have 3 folders (Source, Destination and Archive). Each of them has 3 sub-folders (A, B and C). Only the sub-folders in Source contain 1 or more files. These will be re-written (moved) in Destination or Archive (depends on some requirements).

The files in the sub-folders (A, B and C) in Source will only be rewritten to the sub-folders (A, B, and C) in Destination if:

1. They **ARE** the last created file **AND** if they are at least 120 seconds old.

If they **ARE NOT** the last created file but they **ARE** at least 120 seconds old, they will be moved to the sub-folders (A, B, and C) in Archive.

If they **ARE NOT** the last created file and they **ARE NOT** at least 120 seconds old, they will stay in the current sub-folders (A, B, and C) in Source

During the re-writing process, the content of Power in the file will be multiplied by 10. 
[![which looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee0r7.png ]

This is the code I have, I get the following error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ':'`

Can someone help and tell what I'm doing wrong and why nothing is getting re-written/moved or deleted? Much appreciated!

```
import os, os.path
import time

#Make source, destination and archive paths.
src = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source'
dst = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Destination'
arc = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Archive'

os.chdir(src)

#Now we want to get the absolute paths of the files which will be used to re-write the files.
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    src_path = os.path.join(src, root)
    dst_path = os.path.join(dst, root)
    arc_path = os.path.join(arc, root)


    for f in files:
        src_fpath = os.path.join(src_path, f)
        dst_fpath = os.path.join(dst_path, f)
        arc_fpath = os.path.join(arc_path, f)

#Get only the newest files inside the src_fpath and store it in newest_file_paths.
        newest_file_paths = max(src_fpath, key=os.path.getctime)


#Now we start reading data from the old files, write it into the new files and delete the old files.        
        with open(src_fpath, 'r') as read1, open(dst_fpath, 'w') as write1, open(arc_fpath, 'w') as write2:
            data = {
                    'Power': None,
                    }

            for line in read1:
                splitter = (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()
#If the file(s) ARE the last created file(s) AND if they are at least 120 seconds old. Rewrite in Destination and remove in Source.
                if read1 == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) < time.time() - 120 and Item in data: 
                    Content = str(int(Content) * 10)
                    write1.write(ID+'\t'+Item+'\t'+Content+'\t'+Status+'\n') 
                    write1.write(line)
                    os.remove(src_fpath)
#If the file(s)  ARE NOT the last created file(s) but they ARE at least 120 seconds old. Rewrite in Archive and remove in Source                   
                elif read1 == newest_file_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_file_paths) > time.time() - 120 and Item in data:
                    write2.write(line)
                    os.remove(src_fpath)
#If they ARE NOT the last created file and they ARE NOT at least 120 seconds old. Stay in Source.                   
                else:
                    continue
```

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring things so you first figure out the operations to do, then apply them separately, instead of having one complicated loop.  Also, I don't think the combination of `os.walk()` from the current directory, and joining the absolute paths to them makes much sense – you might want to look at `os.path.relpath()` and join partial paths relative to `src_path` to your destination and archive paths.

Comment: @AKX I think it has to be done in a loop, because if I don't use a loop and apply everything separately things will only be done for 1 file. It must be done for all the files in all in the sub-folders. I already tried to break things up in multiple loops but that only does it for 1 file at a time.

Comment: You do need to use a loop, yes, but things would become clearer if you don't do the reading/writing/deletion in it. First find the files, figure out what to do with them into e.g. an `operations` list-of-dicts, then process them separately in another loop.

Comment: @AKX I think I get you, but I find it difficult to really implement what you are saying? If i dont do the reading/writing/deletion in my loop, my whole loop is gone. Thats all what the loop is actually doing.

Is it possible for you to edit my code to your standards?

Comment: I sketched an answer that might help. Ps. using `os.chdir()` is generally bad practice; it makes it harder to reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you started with what I mean in the comments:

```py
import os, os.path
import time

def rewrite(src_fpath, dst_fpath):
    # Ensure the directory exists:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst_fpath), exist_ok=True)

    with open(src_fpath, "r") as read1, open(dst_fpath, "w") as write1:
        for line in read1:
            (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()
            Content = str(int(Content) * 10)
            write1.write(ID + "\t" + Item + "\t" + Content + "\t" + Status + "\n")
            write1.write(line)
    print("Wrote", dst_fpath, "based on", src_fpath)
    # Uncomment this to actually remove the originals:
    # os.remove(src_fpath)



def process(src_dir, dst_dir, arc_dir, max_age=120):
    operations = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_dir):
        if not filenames:
            # Empty directory, skip
            continue
        rel_dir = os.path.relpath(dirpath, src_dir)
        filename_to_ctime = {
            filename: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            for filename in filenames
        }
        newest_ctime = max(filename_to_ctime.values())
        for filename, ctime in filename_to_ctime.items():
            abspath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            age = time.time() - ctime
            # TODO: is this logic correct?
            if age >= max_age:
                # Move file(s) with newest ctime to dst_dir, everything else to arc_dir
                new_root = dst_dir if ctime == newest_ctime else arc_dir
                new_path = os.path.join(new_root, rel_dir, filename)
                operations.append(("rewrite", abspath, new_path))
            else:
                operations.append(("noop", abspath))
    for operation, *args in operations:
        print(operation, args)
        if operation == "rewrite":
            rewrite(args[0], args[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process(src_dir="./src", dst_dir="./dst", arc_dir="./arc")
```

For instance, if I have a structure like

```
|____src
| |____a
| | |____2.txt
| | |____1.txt
| |____b
| | |____5-old.txt
| | |____4.txt
| | |____3.txt
```

where `5-old.txt` is artificially oldened,

the output is

```
('rewrite', './src/a/1.txt', './arc/a/1.txt')
('rewrite', './src/a/2.txt', './dst/a/2.txt')
('rewrite', './src/b/3.txt', './arc/b/3.txt')
('rewrite', './src/b/4.txt', './dst/b/4.txt')
('noop', './src/b/5-old.txt')
```

Comment: Okkay your code looks really complicated, but we will try to get along with it. I ran your code, with the directory paths I already had. I see no errors, which is good. But nothing has been moved/rewritten...

Comment: That's the TODO comment. You'd implement `rewrite` now, as a simple function that takes a source path and a destination path and does whatever you need. (Next time, read the code through before running it?)

Comment: I try my best, but I 've just started with Python so I'm not yet a professional with it. Is it possible to combine my code with yours? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Fine... I added the code to actually do a similar rewrite of `src_fpath` to `dst_fpath` as you had before (but the deletion bit is currently commented out).

Comment: thank you. But the files have not been moved/rewritten. Maybe forgot to call the functions somewhere? I have no errors but It does say as a code analysis: local variable data is assigned to but never used....

Comment: That `data` was in your code, but yeah, it is unused. I added a bit of logging, so you can see when a new file gets created.

Comment: Okay I feel sorry to say it, but I've ran your code and my destination and archive folders are still empty. Meanwhile the Source folder still contains all files...

Comment: What does it print? Does it say it's going to rewrite things? Or are all of the files too old for the script to do anything, for example?

Comment: It does not print anything and everything stays the same. Nothing has been re/written or moved. Old files should not make sense because I want to move files who are at least 120 seconds old. So the max age doesn't matter, its the minimal age that should matter....very weird that the script does nothing but does not show any errors also.

Comment: It does print the operations it would do. Are you sure your paths are correct in the first place?

Comment: what paths are you talking about. I just copied your code, pasted in my IDE and ran in. I did not edit anything....

Comment: The src_dir/dst_dir/arc_dir at the very bottom. With "I ran your code, with the directory paths I already had.", I thought you'd changed them in the code.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking men but I really don't get you and I really want to understand it. English is also not my native language. With what do I need to change those paths? I tried everything, but still nothing happens....Does it have to do with any of my paths I used when I asked my questions?

Comment: At the very bottom of the revised code I posted is the call to `process()`; you'd need to make it something like `process(src_dir=r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source', dst_dir=r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Destination', arc_dir=r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Archive')`

Comment: Ahh yes! 1 file from Source A got moved to Archive A but became blank when it entered Archive. By the way now we receive an error saying:  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Content'

Comment: Yes, because there's something broken in the "rewrite" function. But now you have the tools to fix that.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help!

Comment: 1 more question. Could you add more comments in your code so I exactly know what your code is doing line by line? Much appreciated men :)